# Unable to find BLE device when type is STEP_COUNT_DELTA

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, sony, google-fit

I am using the Google fit API to connect with a Sony Smartband2 band.
All I am trying to do right now, is scan and claim a device.

(Following [This Fitness ble guide](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/ble-sensors) )

I can find and claim my device, when I set the data type as TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM. However, when I set it to TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA or TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE, I am unable to find the device.

What maybe the issue?
I know that later I will also need to use the Sensors API, but to find the device, I do not need it, right?

To build the api client:

```
mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Fitness.BLE_API)
                .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ))
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

To scan for BLE device:

```
PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = Fitness.BleApi.startBleScan(
                mApiClient,
                new StartBleScanRequest.Builder()
                .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
                //.setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                //.setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
               .setBleScanCallback(bleScanCallback)
               .build());
```

Here, when I use any of the commented statements, I do not get any results.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Looking at the [Data Type reference page](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType), I don't think they are entirely interchangeable as there some [reading sessions](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history) mentioned that must be done for TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA unlike for TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM which is instantaneous.

Answer (score 1):

SmartBand 2 doesn't deliver step count through the Sensors API. Most bands don't. You can obtain step count from the History API in bigger chunks (EG ~1 min) and match that with BPM from the Sensor API.

I'm testing with multiple brands and bands and most don't deliver steps. The SmartBand 2 has the highest resolution BPM of any band I've tested, including bands that sell for 4x the price, and because of that the SmartBand 2 is my personal choice for everyday use and testing - but I really wish Sony would either add live steps to the SmartBand 2 or release a new SmartBand with it.

Comment: What do you mean when you say match that with BPM?

Comment: BPM is the only type of live data you can get. If you only want "live" Steps then your only option is to do something like query the history API every 10 seconds for a single bucket with a size of 10 seconds or something like that. I'm not actually sure off hand what the minimum bucket size is - but if the buckets are too small you don't get good data anyway (steps get lumped at specific intervals) so maybe this isn't a viable solution, but as far as I know it's your only option.

We're querying every 1 minute with a 1 minute bucket and that seems to be working OK.

Comment: That makes sense. How do you integrate the Ble api and the History api in a single app? They seem independent of each other. 
What I mean is, the Ble api is scanning and claiming my smartband, and the History api is getting data, but I don't think it knows it needs to consider data from band + phone. How did you achieve this?

Comment: You mean the Sensors API, which doesn't actually claim/steal the data. All that data is still being logged into the History API by Google Fit and through the built in bridge in LifeLog if you have it enabled to share data with Google Fit. You can request access and permission to both the Sensors and History API with the same builders. EG:

```
mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
    .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ))
    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ))
    ...
```

Comment: By the way, if you're going to try and get data from the BLE API you're going to have to account for the fact that most devices have a secondary data correction process which fixes mistaken steps or strange readings - and pretty much every device has completely different data quality. Different brands offer their own API's but the quality of data is broad. Sony has very high quality formatted data, Lenovo is OK, Garmin is actually awful to the point of I can't believe anybody uses their devices.... Either choose one brand or just stick to things that actually run their data through Google Fit.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I have concluded as follows:
1)Lifelog is now a completely closed ecosystem.
2)Google fit app and Google fit platform are two separate things, the former using the tools provided by the latter
3)Lifelog app by Sony has an option to sync with the Google fit app (nothing to do with the platform)
How does the lifelog bridge you mention matter in this case? 
Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: You're wrong :D . Basically Google Fit is only an aggregation tool for fitness data, it doesn't handle any external sensors other than the pedometer found in phones [and Google Wear devices?]. Smart bands and fitness/activity trackers rely on their own apps to gather data from their devices. Some apps, like LifeLog, provide a bridge that feeds that data into Google Fit. LifeLog is actually one of the few apps that does do this, and it does it well. Garmin/Lenovo/Mi basically don't. If you want data from Google Fit derived from a smart band then Sony is probably the only option for usable data.

Comment: Oh. But Lifelog APIs are not available! So my only option is to use History Api of Google fit while my band is connected via the app provided by Sony for Smartband2?

Comment: LifeLog has an API, search for "Sony Developer Portal" and "LifeLog SDK". You'll get cleaner data than Google Fit because the data hasn't been homogenized by whatever Google Fit does, but you can still get perfectly usable data from Google Fit and you have the advantage of being able to support other health trackers if/when they synchronize with Google Fit.

Comment: I think the lifelog is no longer available, https://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Lifelog/How-can-developer-access-Lifelog-API-now/td-p/1246635
Anyway, Google fit does seem to be working. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I didn't realize! I had tried it around May and it was actually pretty good. I wonder if they'll re-open it again in the future.