# Unable to retrieve STEP_COUNT via my app from Sony Smartband2

Tags: android, api, bluetooth-lowenergy, sony, google-fit

This is not a repeated question as all other questions either refer to the REST Api or retrieve step count from the device (usually the phone) on which the app is running. It is also different from android wear questions, as no separate app can be built for the Smartband2.

I want to retrieve the heart rate and the step count. I am successfully able to get the heart-rate via the [BLE Api](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

However, for the step-count I've been having a lot of trouble.
I understand that the best way to get the step-count is through Google Fit APIs.
I tried using the [Sensor Api](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors), but only my phone on which the app is running gets listed as a Data Source. 
On using the [Google fit BLE Api](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/ble-sensors) ,the band gets detected only when I search for TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, but not when TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE or TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA

From the comment by noogui [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46620944/unable-to-find-ble-device-when-type-is-step-count-delta), I understand I'll have to use the Recording and History Api.

On the other hand, there's an option to create [Additional Sensor](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/new-sensors)from similar questions posted earlier.

I'm utterly confused as how to go about this now.

TLDR: Could someone please list out the steps and the APIs I will need to get step-count data from Smartband2? An example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the heart-rate and step-count data using the following method:

1. Pair the Smartband2 with the official Sony Smartband2 app.
2. In the app: settings -> Google fit -> Turn on
3. Write an app that uses the History api from Google Fit. Example: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/tree/master/BasicHistoryApi
4. Fetch data for every minute for last ten minutes for Heart-rate and step-count

No Ble api or other additional raw sensor creation was required.

Answer (score 1):

The SmartBand2 matches step data against the step counter in the phone to provide a more accurate reading, and because of that you can't get step delta or cadence from the Sensors API. You can either try using the LifeLog SDK (which I haven't tried but it looked like you could use it for semi live sensor data) or grab step data from the History API.

And before you complain about not getting live data let me just say I'm working with a bunch of test units from different makers and the SmartBand 2 has the cleanest and most accurate data stream of any of them. The lack of live step count is a pain but most bands don't deliver that anyway, and the ones that do that I know about have turned out to be overpriced garbage in every other respect.